# Pgfplot axis and axis label cutomization

Tags: pgfplots

Well, simply, my code gives the graph below.
[image: What I have.]

But what I want is something like Fig. 30 (p. 56, Advanced Engineering Mathematics, 9th Ed. by Irvine Kreszig).

[image: What I want]

`\ssfamily` font for the tick label, `axis label` position and a bit more space for it.

Preamble:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    \pgfplotsset{small, every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},
every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}
```

My code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        axis lines= middle,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xlabel=$t$,
        height=100pt,
        ymax=3, ymin=-1,
        minor y tick num=1,
        minor x tick num=1,     
        restrict y to domain=-20:20,
]

\addplot[
    thick,
    orange,
    domain=0:15,
    samples=100,
%   fill=orange!60!white,
]
{(3-2*x)*exp(-0.5*x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The sample function, $y=(3-2x)e^{-0.5x}$.}
\end{figure}
```

Sorry, if it's long a bit.

Comment: On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Can you give your code?

Answer (score 7):

This is one attempt where the second set of pgfplotsset{....} is to set the font family and the following two commands is to rename the `\figurename` and numbering.

```
\renewcommand\figurename{Fig.}
\setcounter{figure}{29}
```

and x and y label position are allocated to location at (x,y) via

```
ylabel=$y$, y label style={at={(0.05,1)}},
xlabel=$t$, x label style={at={(1,0.3)}},
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}        %%% newly added for font family
\pgfplotsset{
compat=newest, 
small, every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},
every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}
}

\pgfplotsset{                            %%% newly added for font family setting
  tick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
  every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
%  legend style = {font=\sansmath\sfamily},
  label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily}
}

\renewcommand\figurename{Fig.}
\setcounter{figure}{29}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[inner sep=0.2cm]

\begin{axis}[
        axis lines= middle,
        ylabel=$y$, y label style={at={(0.05,1)}},  %%% newly added
        xlabel=$t$, x label style={at={(1,0.3)}},   %%% newly added
%        height=100pt,
        ymax=3, ymin=-1,
        minor y tick num=1,
        minor x tick num=1,     
        restrict y to domain=-20:20,
        width=8cm, height=5cm,                      %%% newly added 
]

\addplot[
    thick,
    orange,
    domain=0:15,
    samples=100,
%   fill=orange!60!white,
]
{(3-2*x)*exp(-0.5*x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Solution in Example 4}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It's good. However, the `axis x label` needs to be below the axis and for y to the left, like the figure.

Comment: @Milad -- OK, for `axis x label` uses (1,-0.05) and for `axis y label` uses (-0.12,1.2). Actually you could try (0,0) and (1,1) to see that the label will be located at lower left and upper right corners forming a rectangle. Use negative values for reverse directions. Thus you could put the label anywhere.